# Access Violation when calling C++ DLL from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, cygwin, gnu

I'm trying to compile libraries built for UNIX on Windows and then invoke them from a C# application. Specifically, I'm working with the [FLINT](https://github.com/flintlib/flint) library for fast integer multiplication (among other things). I managed to get the library to build using Cygwin and the GNU toolchain, and have been able to invoke it from a basic C++ application without any issue (also compiled using Cygwin + GNU toolchain).

However, when I try to invoke a function from the DLL in C# it crashes with an access violation.

My first idea was to build a C/C++ layer in MS Visual Studio and compile that as a DLL so I could directly manage the invocation from within Visual Studio once I built the C# part, but compiling FLINT with MSVC (or Clang) has proven to be very difficult (I get a lot of errors that seem to be related to macros defined specifically for the GNU toolchain, but some of them are seemingly more esoteric and I haven't been able to work through them).

Instead, I built a very simple C++ DLL outside of Visual Studio (using Cygwin and GNU again) to simplify invoking a single function from the FLINT library. The header file looks like this:

```
#pragma once
#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport )
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include "flint.h"
#include "fmpz.h"
#include "fmpz_factor.h"
#include "fmpz_mpoly.h"
#include "profiler.h"
extern "C"
{
    DllExport void FactorInteger_Alt(const char *str);
    DllExport int FactorIntegerDirect(int x);
}
```

and the C# side looks like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
namespace CsFlintApi
{
    public class CsFlintApi
    {
        public static void IntegerFactorizationAlt(String str)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(str, 1000);
            IntFacAlt(stringBuilder);
        }

        public static void IntegerFactorizationDirect(int x)
        {
            int y = IntFacDirect(x);
            Console.WriteLine(y);
        }

        [DllImport("flintapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "FactorInteger_Alt")]
        internal static extern void IntFacAlt(StringBuilder stringBuilder);

        [DllImport("flintapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "FactorIntegerDirect")]
        internal static extern int IntFacDirect(int x);
    }
}
```

Both invocations fail with access violation errors. Is this a fundamental issue with calling Cygwin built DLLs from C#, or some other problem?

I should also add that all of the dependent DLLs were placed directly in the bin folder for the C# project (libflint, flintapi, cygwin1, cygstdc++, cyggmp, cygmpfr, cyggcc_s-seh-1, and kernel32), which might also have something to do with it - maybe that's not the right way to do it?

EDIT:

Made changes according to suggestions made in comments, neither of which resolved the issue.

Comment: First do not use classes on native side... Export plain function... Second std::string will not work at all

Comment: You are using CallingConvention.StdCall which is wrong if you are interfacing with a c++ application unless the c++ was built with StdCall.  StdCall is windows convention and not c lanaguage.

Comment: I switched the native side to exporting plain functions and changed CallingConvention.StdCall to CallingConvention.Cdecl (also removed the method using std::string which was unused anyway). Same errors occur.

Comment: What size is `int` in your C++ build, is it 32 or 64 bit? Also `[DllImport("flintapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "FactorInteger_Alt")] internal static extern void IntFacAlt(StringBuilder stringBuilder);` should be `[DllImport("flintapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "FactorInteger_Alt")] internal static extern void IntFacAlt([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string str);`

Comment: int is 32 bits by default in both my C++ build and C#.

Comment: Windows and Cygwin 64 bit are using different assumption on Data model https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/programming.html#gcc-64. Additional check  malloc reserved memory between the two